# passing custom message id parameter in sendgrid while sending email and how can it be get from webhook

Tags: .net-core, sendgrid

I am trying to passing custom message id (X-Message-Id) from while sending email.
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

```
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Ravi Kumar"),
                Subject = "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
                HtmlContent = "<body><a href='http://www.sendgrid.com'>SendGrid</a></body>",
               
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Ravi CIPL"));
```

How can i pass custom X-Message-Id to sendgrid that can be get from the webhook event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a header to an email in [SendGrid C#](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) using the `msg.AddHeader` method:

```cs
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    From = new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Ravi Kumar"),
    Subject = "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
    HtmlContent = "<body><a href='http://www.sendgrid.com'>SendGrid</a></body>",           
};
msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Ravi CIPL"));
msg.AddHeader("X-Message-ID", myMessageId);
```